# Help with $\dfrac{dr}{d\theta}$ for $r=2\sec\theta\csc\theta$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find $\dfrac{dr}{d\theta}$ for $r=2\sec\theta\csc\theta$.

My try:

$$r^{\prime}=2[\sec\theta(-\csc\theta\cot\theta)+\csc\theta(\sec\theta\tan\theta)]$$

$$r^{\prime}=2\left(\frac{1}{\sin\theta}(-\frac{1}{\cos\theta}\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta})+\frac{1}{\cos\theta}(\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta})\right)$$

$$r^{\prime}=2(-\sec^2\theta+\csc^2\theta)$$
$$r^{\prime}=2\csc^2\theta-2\sec^2\theta$$

This is wrong though, the correct answer is: $$r^{\prime}=2\sec^2\theta-2\csc^2\theta$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your initial derivative is correct: $$r^{\prime}=2[\sec\theta(-\csc\theta\cot\theta)+\csc\theta(\sec\theta\tan\theta)]$$

However, note that: 
$$\csc x = \dfrac{1}{\sin x} \;\text{ and }\;\sec x = \dfrac 1{\cos x}$$

---

$$\begin{align} r' &= 2[\sec\theta(-\csc\theta\cot\theta)+\csc\theta(\sec\theta\tan\theta)] \\ \\& = 2\left(\frac{1}{\cos \theta}\left(-\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}\right)+\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\left(\frac{1}{\cos\theta}\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}\right)\right) \\ \\ \\& = -2 \csc \theta + 2\sec \theta \\ \\ &= 2 \sec \theta - 2\csc \theta\end{align}$$

Comment: Very clean ... +1

Answer (score 3):

You have your definitions mixed up.
$$\sec\theta=\frac{1}{\cos\theta}\qquad\csc\theta=\frac{1}{\sin\theta}$$